# UV map not rendering properly

Tags: rendering, uv

I rendered my car with an unwrapped UV map, and it worked fine (see result image top right hand side).

But afterwards the UV Map seems to be misaligned. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Agatha
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the images alone. Could you post a screenshot of your material's node setup, or perhaps upload your blend file? Have you tried explicitly attaching a n UV node to the images vector input socket? Anyway, this all seems very unnecessary, you model seems to be using simple solid colors alone, this could be easily achieved with a few different materials and a bunch of material slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we UV unwrap a model, blender knows the image and uvmap that we are working with and helps us by using it in the viewport shading to make unwrapping easier.

The uvmap that blender uses in the viewport also needs to be setup in the material before the render engine will know to use it. It may be that you had it setup before but inadvertently removed it by mistake.

Under your image details you have a Vector input that you need to connect your uvmap to. Click on default and select UV under Texture Coordinate.

[image: add texture node]

If you were using the node editor, it would look like this -

[image: node editor]

If you have multiple UVMap's setup on your model you can use a UVMap node instead of the Texture Coordinate node to select which UVMap to use.

[image: uvmap node]